# how to vertically align flexed items after using css before content in one of the flexed items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align to flexed items.  the second flexed item contains a form button with tex of a different size added before the submit button. The text before lines up perfectly with the button text.  However the second flexed item will not vertically align with the second flexed item.

Any pointers as to where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Thanks

```css
#intro {
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;  
    }

    button {
      border: none;
      background: transparent;
      padding: 0 0 0 1em;
      
    }

    #intro h1,
    #intro button {
      font-size: 3rem;
      color: green;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    button#create-btn:before{
        content:" +";
        font-size:2em;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #a-txt{
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="intro">
      <div>
        <h1>My Text Heading</h1>
      </div>
      <form>
        <button type="reset" id="create-btn"><span id="a-txt">Reset</span></button>
      </form>
    </section>
```

Comment: Just add align-items:center; to your #intro in css. p.s what is flex-direction:center? center is not valid. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

Comment: Hi Sifili corrected the error, sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees and overlook the obvious... typo. Vinicius is correct, I'm trying to align the text vertically so the text before the + lines up like the text after the + Not sure what making the button element a  flex container will achiev

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it this way. Even though it's not centered geometrically, it should be centered optically for a better user experience.

```css
   #intro {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center 
}


button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#intro h1,
#intro button {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: green;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button#create-btn:before{
    content:" +";
    font-size: 2em;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
    <section id="intro">
      <div>
        <h1>My Text Heading</h1>
      </div>
      <form>
        <button type="reset" id="create-btn"><span id="a-txt">Reset</span></button>
      </form>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that what you want is the flex-direction: column

Here is a very compressive guide for flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
#intro {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;  
    }

    button {
      border: none;
      background: transparent;
      padding: 0 0 0 1em;
      
    }

    #intro h1,
    #intro button {
      font-size: 3rem;
      color: green;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    button#create-btn:before{
        content:" +";
        font-size:2em;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #a-txt{
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="intro">
      <div>
        <h1>My Text Heading</h1>
      </div>
      <form>
        <button type="reset" id="create-btn"><span id="a-txt">Reset</span></button>
      </form>
    </section>
```

Comment: I think OP want vertical align not vertical position

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not understand the issue.